How to write text to currently opened Apache OpenOffice Writer document
Using c#, I am loading a new Writer document and writing a text into it.
(My version is Apache OpenOffice 4.1.4).
I have referred to below link and done some changes and was able to load a document and write text into it.
Open LibreOffice writer and load/close a document using C# CLI
But I want to write the text into an already opened Writer document. Unable to do this.
Tried with all TargetFrameName parameters in my code but it is not working. From https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/frame/XComponentLoader.html:









_blank
Always creates a new frame.


_default
Special UI functionality (e.g. detecting already loaded documents, using empty frames, or creating new top frames as fallback).


_self, ""
Means the frame itself.


_parent
Addresses the direct parent of the frame.


_top
Indicates the top frame of the current path in the tree.


_beamer
Means a special sub frame.



My code snippet:
string url = @"private:factory/swriter"; // this means brand new doc opened to write
PropertyValue[] propVals = new PropertyValue[0];
//tragteframename = "_blank", "trame", "_default", "","_self", "_parent","_top", "_beamer"
var SearchFlags = 2;
XComponent oDoc = oDesk.loadComponentFromURL(url, "_blank", 2, propVals);

if (oDoc == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Document is empty");
}
else
{
    //stardesktop.loadComponentFromURL(sNewfileFormName,"_blank",0,array()) ' _blank open a new view
    //stardesktop.loadComponentFromURL(sNewfileFormName, "_default", 0, array()) ' sets focus to the document

    string docText = "<b>This will</b> be my first paragraph.\n\r";
    docText += "This will be my second paragraph.\n\r";
    ((XTextDocument)oDoc).getText().setString(docText);
}

From the above code, these lines open a new Writer document always and write the text.
string url = @"private:factory/swriter"; // this means brand new doc opened to write
PropertyValue[] propVals = new PropertyValue[0];
//tragteframename = "_blank", "trame", "_default", "","_self", "_parent","_top", "_beamer"
var SearchFlags = 2;
XComponent oDoc = oDesk.loadComponentFromURL(url, "_blank", 2, propVals);`

But I want to open a new Writer document and write the text into that already opened document.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Okay, this is unrelated to the question, and I know this isn't Software Recs, but... notice how the SO link from 9 years ago was about LibreOffice? That's because it was better even at that time, and by now, Apache OpenOffice is badly out of date — please don't use or ask about it anymore.

Anyway, I've read your question but am not clear on what you want. It says, "these lines open a new text document always and write the text." Yes, that's true. Then the question says, "I want to open a new text document and write the text into that already opened text document." But isn't that just what you said the code already does?

Perhaps instead of creating a new document with a factory URI, are you trying to open an already existing document from a known file path, as in @user2338150's answer? Or do you want to use an already existing window instead of _blank?
